# What are better ways to avoid using method calls within Angular Templates?

Tags: angular, templates, optimization, ngfor, angular-changedetection

I am trying to avoid using method calls within Angular Templates as they are non-performant there. Lets say I have a list of names:

```
const names: string[] = ['Billy', 'Mandy', 'Carl', 'Sheryl']
```

and in my template im using an ngFor to iterate the list and print the names:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <p>{{ name }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

But now I need to only display the name if it starts with an 'S' so I change to:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <p *ngIf="doesNameStartWithS(name)">{{ name }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Now I have a method in my template which I know is going to run more times than is necessary. To avoid this I could do something like:

```
// this runs whenever the names list changes
const nameStartsWithSList: boolean[] = this.names.map((name: string): boolean => this.doesNameStartWithS(name));
```

and then change my template to:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names; let i = index;">
  <p *ngIf="nameStartsWithSList[i]">{{ name }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

but this has introduced a new list entirely to avoid the method call in the template. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very interesting question.

One possible solution would be to pass the prefix and field to the directive and manipulate it accordingly. You could probably use the renderer2 as a better solution to present the paragraph with the field you want, but it was just to showcase it works.

```
@Input() chars: string;
@Input() field: string;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.field.toLowerCase().includes(this.chars.toLowerCase())) {
    (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).innerHTML = `<p>${this.field}</p>`;
  }
}
```

Another thing (which I actually just realized) is that you can use the directive as a component too.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <showIfStartsWith chars="s" [field]="name"></showIfStartsWith>
</ng-container>
```

Full demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srnai1?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Edit:**
Found another solution less weird, without using the directive as a component. [Demo V2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iu8d59?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Edit 2:**
Found another solution, using the directive as a structural directive, showcasing how do you pass multiple parameters to it. [Demo V3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hcgxyw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: i dont know why I did not think to use a structural directive for this, ive taken your example and attempted to make a reusable dynamicRender structural directive that takes an argument and a function. if the outcome of the function using the argument is true it shows the component, otherwise it clears it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6ypu3j. You should be able to comment/uncomment the standard for loop and click the Something button to show that the function is called an unnecessary amount of times if the standard loop is there, and not when the dynamically rendered loop is there

Comment: Exactly, as I've shown in the demo v3. So, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to have your list manipulated in the ts file.

if your starting list is:

```
const names: string[] = ['Billy', 'Mandy', 'Carl', 'Sheryl']
```

set it up like

```
output(array, modifier) {
***modify array to return only starting with modifier letter***

return modifiedArray
}

modifier: string = 's'

const names: string[] = output(['Billy', 'Mandy', 'Carl', 'Sheryl'], modifier)
```

then use

```
<div *ngFor="let name of names"> ...
```

Comment: that seems like a pretty good idea although ideally we wont be modifying anything, because if my component modifies an array that was input to it, it will modify it from where it got it from as well. I could see having an input that is my array of names and in onChanges for that input set a new field by doing .map on the original array

Comment: In your example you're setting a new array with const in your component so I didn't assume it was meant to be from an input. If you don't want to modify the original array you can just display a modified copy of the input array.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case I would use a pipe which transforms or filters the given data, something like this:

first-upper.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'firstUpper',
})
export class FirstUpperPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, letter: string): any {
    if(value.startsWith(letter)){
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

After all in your template you can use like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <p>{{ name | firstUpper:'S' }}</p>
</ng-container>
```

You should import this pipe in your pipes.module.ts if you have or app.module.ts declaration section.

Comment: seems like with this solution we'd only be transforming data and it would still be present in the dom. Does not returning a value from a pipe cause it to become empty string?